# Flutter showSnackBar called on null

Tags: flutter

I am trying to show a snack bar in a tabbed flutter app as follows:

```
  var scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    scaffoldKey.currentState
      .showSnackBar(new SnackBar(
        content: new Text("This is a message")
      );
  });
```

But I am getting the error:

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'showSnackBar' was called on null.
```

In the main.dart file I initialize the app as follows:

```
runApp(new MaterialApp(...));
```

And then the snackBar is being called in home.dart which has a tabbed interface:

Widget build (BuildContext context) => new Scaffold(...);

So I'm a bit confused on which scaffold to call the snackbar on, and how, and also why `scaffoldKey.currentState` is null.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to pass Key to `Scaffold` Widget also.

Then you can call -`scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar`

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      .....
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are inside a widget that does not has directly the `return Scaffold(...)` widget, you can do this:

```
Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
 SnackBar(content: Text("Hello from snackbar",
 textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: 
 FontWeight.bold),), duration: Duration(seconds: 3), backgroundColor: Colors.blue,)
);
```

There is no need to create an extra Scaffold widget because the showSnackBar() method requires one, you can reuse.

Comment:  excellent!  using Scaffold.of(context) is very useful when you are using custom widgets instead of spagetti nesting style )

Answer (score 1):

```
     final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldstate= new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
 void _showbar(){
   _scaffoldstate.currentState.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text('Hello world')));
 }
```

In case you are here and the compiler throws this error

*The method 'showSnackBar' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.*

just add **!** in front of currentState.

```
_scaffoldstate.currentState!.showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text('Hello world')));
```